# How do i prove that $| \arg z|<\pi/2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $|1-z|<1$.

Then how do i prove that $| \arg z| < \pi/2$?

This is geometrically trivial, but i dunno how to prove this precisely

Comment: The geometric proof is completely precise but if you do not want to use geometry, try writing $z$ as $x + iy$. Then the condition you have says that $(x - 1)^{2} + y^{2} < 1.$ This implies that $0 < x < 2$ because otherwise $|(x - 1)| \ge 1$. That implies what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set of complex numbers which satisfy $|1- z| < 1$ is the open disk of radius 1 centered at 1. This is contained in the open right half of the complex plane. For complex numbers in the open right half plane, you have 
$$\text{Arg}(z) \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Do you mean the open disc?

Comment: Yes I do. I'll make that edit. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

From a purely algebraic point of view, if $z=re^{i \theta}$ and $(1-z)(1- \overline{z})=|1-z|^2<1$, then you get $r<2 \cos(\theta)$. Therefore, $\cos(\theta)>0$ that is $\theta \in (- \pi/2,\pi/2)$.